# Sql query to find subtotal of distinct column and grand total from a single table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table in which I have 3 columns

```
ID  Amount  District
1   100     A
2   500     B
1   250     A
2   240     B
1   100     A
```

Now I want to display Subtotal of distinct district and Grand total. Please guide me how should I write my sql query.

I want to show output as-

```
District  Subtotal  Grand Total
A          450
B          740        1190
```

Comment: are you using mysql or sql-server ? also post desired output

Comment: _Distinct district_ => `GROUP BY`. _Subtotal, Grand total_ => `SUM`

Comment: It depends on how you want to show the *distinct district and Grand total* as result.

Comment: @amdixon Yes I want to show the result using both mysql and sql. I have also edited my question please check.

Comment: I wont do this in `Sql` may be `UI`can do this easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `SUM` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) to get the grand total, like this:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM data;
```

That'll return a single row containing a single number, the total of all of the `Amount`s in your entire table.

To get the per-district total, combine `SUM` with [a `GROUP BY` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
SELECT SUM(Amount), District FROM data GROUP BY District;
```

This will return a table with one row for each district containing the total for that district.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data in this format you can try using below code :

```
SELECT District As 'District', SUM(Amount) as 'Total' 
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY District
UNION
SELECT 'Grand Total', sum(Amount) 
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the sample table and insert some data

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT, Amount INT, District CHAR(1))

INSERT @tbl
SELECT 1, 100, 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 500, 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 250, 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 240, 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 100, 'A'
```

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.District, 
       CASE WHEN ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @tbl 
                       WHERE District = t.District
                       ORDER BY ID DESC)
            THEN (SELECT SUM(Amount) 
                  FROM @tbl
                  WHERE ID <= t.ID
                  AND District = t.District)
            ELSE ' ' END AS [Subtotal],
       CASE WHEN ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @tbl 
                       ORDER BY District DESC)
            THEN (SELECT SUM(Amount) 
                  FROM @tbl) 
            ELSE ' ' END AS [Grand Total]
FROM @tbl AS t
```

You can do the same thing for MySQL but instead of using `TOP` you need to use `LIMIT`